# Typhoon initializer injection & calling super.init()

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, typhoon

I have a parent and child class and an initializer in the child class that accepts some parameters and then calls super.init() to initialize the properties from the base class.

As I have a lot of child classes I want to reuse code for injecting the parameters but I can't figure out a way of injecting some of the members in the base class definition and the rest of them in the child class definition.

I tried the following:

```
public dynamic func baseManager() -> AnyObject {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(BaseManager.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.useInitializer("initWithBaseParam1:baseParam2:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.baseParam1())
            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.baseParam2())
        }
    }
}

public dynamic func authenticationManager() -> AnyObject {

    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AuthenticationManager.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition.parent = self.baseManager()
        definition.useInitializer("initWithChildParam1:childParam2:baseParam1:baseParam2:") {
            (initializer) in

            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.childParam1())
            initializer.injectParameterWith(self.childParam2())
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error that I use an initializer with 4 parameters but only inject 2 of them. Is there a way I can make this work or do I have to refactor the base params to be properties like the example in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit the initializer from a parent or override it, but unfortunately you can't extend an initializer with extra parameters in addition to those defined in a parent template.

Suggested alternatives:

**Use Property Injection**

Generally we recommend to favor initializer injection it allows the creation of immutable objects and state verification after construction. These drawbacks in property injection can be addressed by:

- Specify [a callback method](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/Types%20of%20Injections#injection-call-backs) to be used after properties have been injected.
- For instances that are designed to be immutable, declare properties as internally read-write, but externally read-only.

**Use composition rather than inheritance**

Another suggestion is to create an appropriately scoped definition that encapsulates the configuration that tends to be used together and inject that.

Depending on the situation this can be advantageous - there's lots of good articles around on 'composition vs inheritance' and when each is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. A bit of a side question - are you looking to add this kind of functionality in newer versions of the framework?

Comment: It is not currently in our backlog, but you'd be welcome to request it.